# Catkin_make error: No such file or directory of a customized header file

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I encountered a catkin_make error and already spent several days of trying to solve it but I could not make it. I hope you guys have any ideas on this. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo version.

The error message I got when doing catkin_make is

`fatal error: AA/AAA.hpp: No such file or directory`, which is placed in a header file I made (`BBB.hpp` as in the below) with `#include <AA/AAA.hpp>`.

The following is how my source folder is organized roughly.

```
/devel
/build
/src
    CMakeLists.txt
    /A
        /AA
            CMakeLists.txt
            package.xml
            /src
                AAA.cpp
            /include
                AAA.hpp
    /B
        /BB
            CMakeLists.txt
            package.xml
            /src
                BBB.cpp
            /include
                BBB.hpp
```

`A` and `B` are directories that include corresponding multiple packages in each of them. What I have basically been trying to do is to use functions of `AA` package from `BB` package. Therefore, `BB` package's `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` files include necessary parts to work with `AA` package. In the bottom, I also attached brief structure of CMakeLists of both `A` and `B`.

The weird thing is when I included `#include <AA/AAA.hpp>` in `BBB.cpp` file, it worked fine. However, when included in `BBB.hpp` file, I got the above error, which is `fatal error: AA/AAA.hpp: No such file or directory`. The followings are CMakeLists of `A` and `B`. Do you guys have any insights on this? I need to define `#include <AA/AAA.hpp>` in `BBB.hpp` file. I really appreciate your help in advance!

CMakeLists.txt of `AA`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(AA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS
    include
  LIBRARIES
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
  DEPENDS
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
   src/AA_main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp"
)

install(
  DIRECTORY doc
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

CMakeLists.txt of `BB`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(BB)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  AA
)

catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include
 LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
 CATKIN_DEPENDS
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/BB_main.cpp
)
add_dependencies(
  ${PROJECT_NAME} 
  DEPS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}}
)
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233511/catkin_make-error:-no-such-file-or-directory-of-a-customized-header-file/) by [yoo00](https://answers.ros.org/users/19901/yoo00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, what I see is: if you want to `#include <AA/AAA.hpp>` the folder structure in `AA` should be:

```
    /AA
        CMakeLists.txt
        package.xml
        /src
            AAA.cpp
        /include
            /AA
                AAA.hpp
```

Otherwise you need to `#include <AAA.hpp>`. However, why the above should work when you include it in the cpp, makes no sense for me...

(minor issue, but i guess just copy-paste-error: in `CMakeLists.txt` of `BB`: `DEPS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}}` has an extra bracket at the end. And from what you post here, you'll probably not need the `add_dependencies` call at all)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yoo00](https://answers.ros.org/users/19901/yoo00/) on 2016-05-03**:
Thanks for your answer! But it still does not work. I also tried absolute path like `#include <../../../AA/AAA.hpp>` but it did not work either. I guess it is because of the CMakeLists setup but I am not sure about that. It looks really weird.. Anyway, I appreciate your tips about minor issues too!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-04**:
could you put a (minimal) example on GitHub and link it here? This should actually be a simple one, but I cannot see more from this.

**Comment by [yoo00](https://answers.ros.org/users/19901/yoo00/) on 2016-05-05**:
Oops. It was my bad. The error was caused by other package I made but the error was pointing to the package I described the above. That was why I was confused. Like you mentioned, it was a really simple mistake. Thanks Mig!